# AJAX Control Toolkit Loading All Scripts

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a bit of a weird problem I can't seem to fix. I am using the AJAX Control Toolkit's **calendar extender** on some of my pages. Despite the information I've found via the web I can't seem to get it working with a regular `ScriptManager` control, it *only* works with a `ToolkitScriptManager`. However I've noticed that when the page loads it adds some 84 script files for every possible control script provided by the toolkit:

[image: A selection of the scripts being loaded]

Is this the expected behaviour, and can I turn it off? I only need it to load the relevant scripts to handle the calendar extender.

Comment: I saw this in my project 4 months ago in my Visual studio in theSolution Explorer. The solution for my was forget Ajax Control Toolkit and migrate to Jquery. Jquery It's much better and when you looking for that How AjaxControlToolkit works you will say "I love you Jquery".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In current version of ACT you can group extenders in bundle and specify which bundles you need to include.
Add `AjaxControlToolkit.config` file to project like here [Codeplex AjaxControlToolkit.config](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SampleWebSites/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxControlToolkit.config), add new controlBundle entry to this file for CalendarExtender like this:

```
<controlBundle name="Calendar">
  <control name="CalendarExtender"></control>
</controlBundle>
```

and specify this bundle in ToolkitScriptmanager control:

```
 <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" CombineScripts="true" 
      ScriptMode="Release" >
      <ControlBundles>
           <ajaxToolkit:ControlBundle Name="Calendar" />
      </ControlBundles>
 </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ControlBundles to solve this, follow [this step](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2013/07/25/july-2013-release-of-the-ajax-control-toolkit) about ControlBundles on how to do it.