# Ajax contol toolkit: how to load only scripts needed now that ToolkitScriptManager is obsolete

Tags: asp.net, webforms, ajaxcontroltoolkit

We are using Ajax Control toolkit.
We installed this:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/AjaxControlToolkit.StaticResources/

We already used ACT for bundling, by setting it in web config:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server" EnableCdn="true" >
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/AjaxControlToolkit/Bundle" />
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
```

We are optimizing the page and we noticed, that script is almost 1MB.

This:

[AJAX Control Toolkit Loading All Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971547/ajax-control-toolkit-loading-all-scripts)

and this:

http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2013/07/25/july-2013-release-of-the-ajax-control-toolkit

would solve our problem.

But in new versions of Ajax Control Toolkit ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager is obsolete, so we can not use ControlBundles in script manager.

My question is: how to load only scripts we need (we are using drop down, rating and slider)?

We are using:

- Ajax Control Toolkit 16.1.0
- .net framework 4.5.1

Edit: what I did so far:
added AjaxControlToolkit.config to root and inserted this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ajaxControlToolkit>
  <controlBundles>
    <controlBundle name="AjaxBundle">
      <control name="CalendarExtender" />
      <control name="ComboBox" />
    </controlBundle>
  </controlBundles>
</ajaxControlToolkit>
```

Added scriptmanager to masterpage:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server" EnableCdn="true" >
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/AjaxControlToolkit/AjaxBundleBundle" />
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Added this to Global asax to application start:

```
BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Script/js-master".Include("~/Scripts/AjaxControlToolkit/AjaxBundle"));
```

On masterpage I also have:

```
<%: System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/Script/js-master") %>
```

I intentionally missed out slider extender (so it shouldn't work), but it is working anyway, so I guess all the Ajax Control Toolkit scripts are loaded.

Web config, also:

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5.1">
```

Comment: You don't need to add `ScriptBundle` into `BundleTable` explicitly. Can you check what scripts are actually loaded in browser's developer console? It might be you load CDN bundle as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can. This feature is kept for backward compatibility.

You don't need to specify it explicitly anymore. Toolkit scans for `AjaxControlToolkit.config` file in application root (specifically, `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath`) and makes control bundles from it.

Comment: I don't have AjaxControlToolkit.config in root yet. I will add it and specify which scripts i want. Care to explain more about HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath setting? I guess, that is configured in web config.

Comment: No, it is hardcoded value: https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/blob/master/AjaxControlToolkit/Bundling/BundleResolver.cs#L144

Comment: So apart from adding AjaxControlToolkit.config file to root and add content I do not need to do anything else?

Comment: You need to specify this bundle as a script, like default bundle: https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/blob/master/AjaxControlToolkit.SampleSite/Layout.master#L17
Keep in mind to add `Control` before bundle name: https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/wiki/Upgrading-from-v7.x-and-below#4---use-microsoftweboptimization-for-bundling-and-minification

Comment: Do not know to do what?

Comment: I named controlBundle in AjaxControlToolkit.config AjaxBundle. I added bundle in Globall.Asax as BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Script/js-master").Include("~/Scripts/AjaxControlToolkit/AjaxBundle")); I also added <%:System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/Content/AjaxControlToolkit/Styles/Bundle") %> to my master page. No succes.

Comment: You can specify `ScriptReference` entry in `ScriptManager`, which is required to make toolkit work. In most cases it is located in Master page. You can check [this link](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/blob/master/AjaxControlToolkit.SampleSite/Layout.master#L17) again to see `ScriptReference` entity syntax.
Adding bundle to BundleTable just tells we can use it, but does no render any bundle to a page.

Comment: Also added, as you stated: <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/AjaxControlToolkit/AjaxBundle" />
            </Scripts> and in AjaxControlToolkit.config I added only <controlBundle name="AjaxBundle">
      <control name="CalendarExtender">
    </controlBundle> so my slider extender shouldn't work, but it is working anyway, so i assume all the Ajax Contol Toolkit scripts are loaded.

Comment: If you name ControlBundle after `AjaxBundle` then Path should be like `~/Scripts/AjaxControlToolkit/AjaxBundleBundle`. Also check you have no other bundle entries like `~/Scripts/AjaxControlToolkit/Bundle`, so scripts may be loaded twice.

Comment: Good point! I altered all of this, edited my question and added progress so far, still no success.

Comment: checked again: although slider is NOT en ajax.config file it is still working. BUT: Ajaxbundle is 163.9KiB - so I guess we were successful.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the js scripts, the toolkit will load a few CSS files too. To prevent it from loading these WebResource.axd with css and image content, you can use web.config:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="ajaxControlToolkit" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxControlToolkitConfigSection, AjaxControlToolkit" requirePermission="false"/>
</configSections>

<ajaxControlToolkit renderStyleLinks="false" />
```

To see the content of the files, in a test project, install the nuget package `AjaxControlToolkit.StaticResources` which has all images, css and js.

For example, I use the CalendarExtender, but I don't want an extra http request to get the little left and right arrows, so I've customised the css to use my own generic sprite. Same for Combobox down arrow, I actually use the Bootstrap caret character/style instead of an image.